# JMeter: JavaScript Variable Changing Values

Tags: javascript, jmeter

i am a newbie in JMeter and while testing Daraz.pk, i came accross a situation in which this tag appears in my response while signUp procedure.

JMeter only captures this response while when i saved the whole response into html file and opened then after full page load the value changes

i need second value which is "3fa9c" in my script and by no mean i am able to get that. i've thoroughly researched but no solution is availabe. Please help me find the solution and it will make my task lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and it needs to be worked around with simple correlation

```
<input class="csrfCharValidation" value="fbfe9" name="RegistrationForm[js_enabled]" id="RegistrationForm_js_enabled" type="hidden">
                                         ^^^^^ here it is
```

You need to design your script as follows:

- Open Sign Up page (HTTP GET request)

  - Extract `csrfCharValidation` input value with one of the following PostProcessors:

    - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
    - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
    - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- Perform Sign Up (POST Request), pass all the required parameters (first/last name, gender, birth date, email, password **and** the value of this `csrfCharValidation` input

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) for detailed information on bypassing CSRF protection in JMeter tests.

Comment: i didn't get it right. infect i cannot find the value of csrfCharValidatio. because when response is recorded by Jmeter, it's value is something like 2,6,4,8,9. i tried correlations and all. which i know. i saved the response in HTML format and i opened it in chrome, it showed the same value 2,6,7,8,9 but when page load from local computer completes, it changes the value to something like 3a5fe. it's a whole new problem. i have been surfing for it since yesterday.

Comment: csrfCharValidation" value="2,5,6,8,9" this is the value which i get in Jmeter response. 
But when i save total response in html format and open it in a browser, when browser is loading the file it remains same but when page is fully loaded this values changes to. 942a7. now how this is possible. how could i apply css, xpath or reg exp to get this value.

Comment: For instance relevant XPath query to extract the dynamic CSRF token will look like `//input[@class='csrfCharValidation']/@value`. See [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guides for more information.